# GNU as: changing output file format

Tags: linux, assembly, elf, gnu-assembler

`as` defaults to ELF. I have some PIC code I would like to assemble to just that - only the raw instructions, no sections, etc. I believe using `nasm` you could achieve this by assembling with no options, and start your code with the `BITS 32` directive (for a 32 bit architecture).

How to with `as`?

System:
- Ubuntu 12.04.
- as 2.2.
- x86 32b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` can only generate ELF output, but you can convert an ELF binary to another format using `objcopy`:

```
objcopy -O binary mybinary.elf mybinary.bin
```

It supports a number of other formats as well as "binary". In particular, it supports "ihex" to produce `.hex` files, which some microcontroller programming tools may require.

Answer (score -1):

-c compile will produce an object file from source

Comment: Thanks for chipping in, but -c is no valid option for (g)as. You probably mean to use it with gcc, where it is, and does create an object file; but (a) that object file is an elf file again (not surprising as gcc relies on as), and (b) the question was mostly to find out if as could do it (because then gcc probably could do it too).